# linux java top cpu issue

Tags: java, linux

I attached 2 photos.

The first with threads view.
The second without.

How come in the second it shows only 100 cpu usage, while in the first when you combine all threads cpu usage it's a much more bigger number?
[image: top command with Treads]

[image: top command without Treads]

Comment: How many cores does your CPU have?

Comment: you have to multiply cpu usage by number of cores.

Comment: about CPU: 4 EC2 Compute Units (2 virtual cores with 2 EC2 Compute Units each)

Comment: tigran, i didnt understand your point :)

Comment: 3100% CPU? ... Java does it again! | @User/OP: It's a bug and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

> How come in the second it shows only 100 cpu usage, while in the first when you combine all threads cpu usage it's a much more bigger number?

I think the answer is that either your `top` command is broken, or it is incompatible with your Linux kernel.  The "%CPU" numbers for the "thread" view are simply nonsensical.